# Menus apper on hover like twitter

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, menu, jquery-hover

I'm working on my own little bookmark project. I'm using rails 3.2.11 and I'll like to add a menu like twitter when hover over a tweet a little menu will show right bellow it. Well if you ever use twitter you know what I mean.

I already try I few things but I can't get then to work.

[jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated...also When I finish with it I will open source, just because I think it will be awesome to have all your bookmarks on the go, I use like 4 different pc during the week and I always forget stuff.

Thanks in advance.

[image: little bookmark]

Comment: can u show the part of code you have tried.?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NCUDP/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NCUDP/4/
I try using this but since I using loops it doesn't work right
I just push the code github if you will like to check it out
https://github.com/cs102/little-bookmark

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.bind`  to show your menu [Here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is the link.

```
$('#elementId or .className').bind('mouseenter',function(){
//Your code to show the menu
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Twitter Bootstrap, which contains lots of CSS/JS utilities for creating websites.

They have the [Tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) plugin or the [Popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) one.

Cheers,